# Remainder of Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

My lecture note says for $f\in C^2 _c $ the $|f(z+h)-(f(z)+f'(z)h+\frac{1}{2}f''(z)h^2)|\le \omega(h)h^2$ where $\omega$ is the modulus of continuity of $f''$.

I have been thinking this for an hour and I cannot get the answer without assuming third derivative.
Could anyone help to show why this is true?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean value form of the Taylor series is
$$f(z+h) = f(z) + f'(z) h + \frac{1}{2} f''(\xi) h^2,$$
for some $\xi$ between $z$ and $z+h$.
Then use $|f''(\xi) - f''(z)| \le \omega(|\xi-z|) \le \omega(h)$.

---

More detail: substituting the mean value form for $f(z+h)$ gives

\begin{align}
&\left|f(z+h) - f(z) - f'(z) h  - \frac{1}{2} f''(z) h^2\right|\\
&\le \frac{1}{2} |f''(\xi) - f''(z)| h^2\\
&\le \frac{1}{2} \omega(h) h^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am a little confused here, do you mean that if the error bound$w(h)h^2$ works for  $|f(z+h)-(f(z)+f'(z)h)|$ it also works for $|f(z+h)-(f(z)+f'(z)h+\frac{1}{2}f''(z)h^2)|$?

Comment: @Sherry See my edit

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thank you so much!